# javascript: range.setStart() INDEX_SIZE_ERR(1)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a range and it's just not working. For now, I'm trying in IE9.

The following gives me a DOMException: INDEX_SIZE_ERR(1). Should it not give me the range bcdef?

```
  <div id = "test" >abcdefghij</div>


 //range =  document.selection.createRange(); //also tried this
 range =  document.createRange();


 node = document.getElementById("test");
 range.setStart(node, 2);
 range.setEnd(node, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support document.selection.createRange() and uses its own syntax (surprised?).

There's an article on QuirksMode about workarounds to this problem. I suggest you read it:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: They do according to their own documentation. I am using IE9. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975303(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And the article that you link to actually says to do it the way that I am trying.